# O notation proof for exponents and power

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory, exponential

I am trying to prove that 4^n is not in the order of O(2^n).

Is this a valid method ?
    4^n >= c*2^n
    => 4^n/2^n >= c
    => 2^n >= c

I got lost here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your method is also concrete. You should proceed in the same direction. Currently, I also don't have a better option.

```
4^n = ((2^2)^n) = (2^2n) = (2^n) * (2^n) > 2^n for all values of n>0.
```

> As, (2^n) * (2^n) > O(2^n) .
>
> This is because (2^n) * (2^n) > c * 2^n. Therefore,there doesn't exist
>   any constant value which is greater than 2^n!

Hence, ***`4^n != O(2^n) as 4^n > 2^n for all values of n>0`***.